# SQL server 2008 naming standards for tables and columns

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the following question regarding the SQL server 2008 naming standards.

1. Should I name a table as singular “Customer” OR “Customers”.
2. If inside the above table I have an ID column; should I name it “CustomerID”, “Customer_ID”, OR “ID” .

Thanks

Comment: I don't know whether there's a rule for that? I tend to name a table that contains more than one thing `Things`, so it would be `Customers`. I name the `ID` column for the `Customers` table `ID` only. Then, in related tables I'd have a `CustomerID` column.

Comment: I'm using same conventions except i prefer Customer_ID as reference column name

Comment: Pick one and stick to it. If you are looking at ORMs e.g. entity framework or rails, have a look at their conventions. If you don't follow and them and then try to wire up the ORM later, it can get well messy.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Use plural, "Customers", the table will hold many rows.
2. Use just "ID", its easier to always use the same and easier when writing queries. ("select x where Customers.ID = 5")

*On a side note*, for other tables referencing the Customers table I would name the referencing column to **something that describes the relation**. Not just "CustomerID" but "PlacedBy_CustomerID" in the orders table, or "PaidBy_CustomerID" in the invoice table. That way the meaning of the relation becomes a bit more present.

Answer (score 0):

I use this notation:

- L_TABLE for lookup tables, F_TABLE for fact table.
- Plural name if a single row describes, for example, a CUSTOMER. The table contains in fact multiple rows (CUSTOMERS) so it will be meaningful.
- Descriptor prefix is useful for join and for readability: if you're not the only one to access to that table it's easier to understand if user query will retrieve CUSTOMER_ID, generic ID, ROW_ID and so on. Think about multiple IDs in the same table referring to different fields (even in other tables).
- Personal point: for an ID in a look up table I will always use L_CUSTOMER_ID, it's quite long but totally clear.